# how to wait for a certain callback method to be called before a function returns in java?

Tags: java, cordova, callback

I am writing a phonegap plugin.My code outline is this

```
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray arg1, String arg2) {
      try{
        if (action.equals("authenticate")) {
           this.startlogin();
           return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
        }
        else {
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        }
       }catch(Exception e){}
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION); 

    }
```

startlogin() method calls a function which has callback method registered which gets called after certain event.i.e startlogin() method returns but a certain method is called after an event occurs which is asynchronous.

```
 public void startlogin(){

    login();//this has callback method
 }
```

how to wait until that callback method is finished before i return from execute method?
Whats the best method in java?

PS:I cannot change execute method prototype since phonegap plugin works on execute method.

Comment: It's been a few years... but do you have a solution for this? I have a similar problem where I'm implementing a 3rd party interface and need to wait for a callback.

Comment: does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're trying to mix synchronous with asynchronous...

What you should really do is have the callback method return the PluginResult.

Cheers,

Comment: I cannot do that.execute method must return pluginresult.its a phonegap plugin entry and exit method.its an interface to the javascript and backend java..

Comment: If that is really your only option you have to poll/busywait in the execute method as outlined by @TheStijn and somehow signal from the callback to the `execute()`method. I think we can provide more useful help if you supply some details on the callback, i.e. how is it registered, do you have control of its implementation etc.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach:

```
if (this.startlogin()) ...

...

public boolean startlogin(){

    return login();
}
```

Comment: Could also be: `while( !this.startlogin() ) { /* nothing*/ }` if `login()` is async.

Comment: login() method has an asynchronous callback method.i.e login() returns  but i want to return from execute until that callback method is executed..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand `i want to return from execute until that callback method is executed`

Comment: sorry..i should be i dont want to return from execute until that callback method is executed..